# Why did my animated Graphics3D stop functioning after Nvidia GPU driver update? Now I have to end Mathematica process in the task manager

Tags: performance-tuning, graphics3d, animation, gpu

The following code used to work fine until just after a recent Nvidia driver update. Running the code causes Mathematica to completely hang and I must end the Mathematica process in the task manager.

The only change to the computer or the OS environment was updating to the latest NVidia video driver.  I would go back to the old driver but I need the new one for other PC software.

After *Shift-Enter* to execute the code, the notebook hangs--actually all of Mathematica hangs.  I can’t do anything in any Mathematica window or process. It acts like it is just completely banging up against processory power or memory.

**Task Manager observations:** for the Wolfram Mathematica process: never more than **18% CPU** and nothing more than **8% GPU**.  Memory usage at **21%**. Power usage is **Very High** but this is because I have power management set for *performance* over *power*.

I have run this right after a clean reboot and with no additional software running or additional background processes.

**Mathematica Version:** 11.3.0.0 (I know, kinda old but it has run without ever a single hitch till now.)

**Hardware setup:** MSI GS65 Stealth, Intel 8th Gen Core i7-8750H, 15GB-RAM, NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060. BTW there is an on-board Intel UHD Graphics 630 video card, but I never use it and it is disabled in the device manager.

I have tried to navigate the Nvidia control panel and optimize when running Mathematica for highest performance.  There are no changes in the Nvidia control panel which seem to make any difference—either better or worse…

Here is the code. It animates a 4D representation of a tesseract:

```
   v = Tuples[{-1,1},4];
   e = Select[Subsets[Range[Length[v]],{2}],Count[Subtract@@v[[#]],0]==3&];
   f = Select[Union[Flatten[#]]&/@Subsets[e,{4}],Length@#==4&];
   f = f/.{a_,b_,c_,d_}:>{b,a,c,d};
   rotv[t_] = (RotationMatrix[t,{{0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0}}].
     RotationMatrix[2 t,{{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1}}].#)&/@v;
   proj[t_]:=Most[#]/(3-Last[#])&/@rotv[t];

   Animate[
      Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[proj[t],
         {RGBColor[.1,1,.4], Specularity[0.75,10], Sphere[Range[16],0.03], 
          Tube[e,0.01], Opacity[0.3], Polygon@f}], Boxed->False, Background->White, 
       PlotRange->1], {t,0,Pi/2}]
```

Comment: On v12.2.0, Win7-x64, 3rdgen i5, 8GB with a radeon 2GB video card, the display is choppy, but it [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3PjR.gif). Since this issue most likely concerns a third-party driver update, you can contact Wolfram support for more guidance.